# How to get domain in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to build unsubscribe link in my email template but problem is i'm using seperate function in my utilites.py file to render my template and don't have access to request. This function is called by schedular in backend.
I tried request.build_absolute_uri and other things but not able create the absulute link

**templates**

```
<body>
    <section class="tour section-wrapper container" id="notify-form">
        <table id='datatable'></table>
        {{ content|safe }}

{#    <a href="{{ request.build_absolute_uri}}{% url 'delete' %}?email={{ sub_email }}">Unsubscribe</a>#}
{#    <a href="{% if request.is_secure %}https:/{% else %}http:/{% endif %}{{ request.get_host }}{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ object.get_absolute_url }}{% url 'delete' %}?email={{ sub_email }}">Unsubscribe</a>#}
        <a href="{% if request.is_secure %}https://{% else %}http://{% endif %}{{ domain }}{% url 'delete' %}?email={{ sub_email }}">Unsubscribe</a>

    </section> <!-- /.tour  </body> -->
```

commented code is also what i tried
tried using Sites framework but that gives doamin as example.com not what I expected

**utility method**

```
def send_notification(dataframe, email):
    subject = 'That’s your subject'
    from_email = 'xxxx@gmail.com'  # 'from@example.com'
    text_content = 'That’s your plain text.'
    subscriber_email = QueryDetails.objects.get(email=email)
    domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
    html_content = get_template('mail_template.html').render({'content': dataframe.to_html(classes=["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"]),'sub_email': subscriber_email, 'domain': domain})
```

Expected out put is if in local domain will be http://127.0.0.1/unsub/?email=xxxx@gmail.com
if in production then http://whateverproductiondomain.com/unsub/?email=xxxx@gmail.com

But if i run the program with one of commented code in template them url generated is /unsub/email=xxxx@gmail.com
and with Sites framework it's http://example.com/unsub/?email=xxxx@gmail.com
any guesses how to do it , send_notification is not getting called from views so can't pass request into it.

Comment: you can try [get_host()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) to get the host name instead, required `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` to be enabled

Comment: but get_host() also requires request which I can't use in this scenario as this send notifcation is not getting called from view function but from backed schedular. View and this template part is toatally different.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `SITE_URL='http://127.0.0.1/'` in settings.py (you have different settings in production and in development).

So you need to pass it to the template:

```
from app.settings import SITE_URL

def send_notification(dataframe, email):
    subject = 'That’s your subject'
    from_email = 'xxxx@gmail.com'  # 'from@example.com'
    text_content = 'That’s your plain text.'
    subscriber_email = QueryDetails.objects.get(email=email)
    domain = SITE_URL
    html_content = get_template('mail_template.html').render({'content': dataframe.to_html(classes=["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"]),'sub_email': subscriber_email, 'domain': domain})
```

And in template:

```
 <a href="{{ domain }}{% url 'delete' %}?email={{ sub_email }}">Unsubscribe</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it dynamically, you can use `request.get_host()`.

For example, in a views function, you can pass it to the context using `context['host'] = request.get_host()` and call the variable in templates using `{{ host }}`.

When I run it locally, I get 'localhost:8000' and when in production, I get e,g., 'domain.com'. You can then treat it as a string to append or prepend that URL with whatever you need to make it useful (for example, to add `http://` in front or `/whatever/path` in the back).

I prefer this way instead of an alternative, like hard-coding the domain name in an environment variable and calling it because that's kind more messy to manage.

Comment: That's a issue, can't use view function as send_notification method will be initiated by backend schedular there is no view function in picture so can't pass request

Comment: @vineetsingh If there's no way to use request, I might suggest adopting Waldemar's answer. Aside from using environment variables, there's a hacky way to make it automatic, like setting if DEBUG=True, use SITE_URL: your domain. Else, use SITE_URL: local host.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it through view function

```
domain = request.META["HTTP_HOST"]
```

Comment: That's a issue, can't use view function as send_notification method will be initiated by backend schedular there is no view function in picture so can't pass request.